# Script executes once, then (slowly) a second time after page loads

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Following [this](http://ekragency.com/canvas-based-scroll-controlled-backgroud-video-use-parallax-style-web-design/) tutorial for creating scroll-controlled background video. When I execute the js file (below), I get the 404 errors below one-by-one. However, if I add console.log("THIS IMG: " + img) to the script I can see that the code has already executed (twice) prior to these errors being generated.

The one-by-one errors are noticeably slowing down the loading of my page, and the script should only be executing once. I did a file search (below) for background_vid.js and only have once instance of it, so I don't understand why it is executing more than once. Any help much appreciated.

**background_vid.js**

```
var totalImages = 183;
var images = new Array();
  for(var i = 1; i <= totalImages; i++) {
      var filename = 'look_up/img_' + i + '.png'; // Filename of each image
      var img = new Image;
      img.src = filename;
      // console.log("THIS IMG: " + img);
      images.push(img);
  }

var canv = document.getElementById('background');
$(canv).width($(window).width()).height($(window).height());
```

**about.html.erb**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">

            <!--viewport goodness http://enva.to/A79s3G-->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <title>Title</title>

            <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'styles', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
            <%= javascript_include_tag 'skrollr', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
            <%= javascript_include_tag 'background_vid', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        </head>

    <body>
      <header class="band" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-300="background-position:0px -120px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns sixteen" data-0="opacity: 1" data-180="opacity: 0">
              <h1>Some text</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
      </header>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        var s = skrollr.init();

        skrollr.init({
          forceHeight: false
        });

      </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Error**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/look_up/img_1.png 404 (Not Found)
about:28 GET http://localhost:3000/look_up/img_3.png 404 (Not Found)
about:28 GET http://localhost:3000/look_up/img_2.png 404 (Not Found)
about:28 GET http://localhost:3000/look_up/img_4.png 404 (Not Found)
about:28 GET http://localhost:3000/look_up/img_5.png 404 (Not Found)
about:28 GET http://localhost:3000/look_up/img_6.png 404 (Not Found)
etc
```

**Error with print out demonstrating 2x expected image objects**

```
(366)THIS IMG: [object HTMLImageElement]
about:28 GET http://localhost:3000/look_up/img_1.png 404 (Not Found)
about:28 GET http://localhost:3000/look_up/img_2.png 404 (Not Found)
etc
```

**Search for script:**

```
/Users/username/Desktop/projectname/blog/config/initializers/assets.rb:
   12  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( styles.css )
   13  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( skrollr.js )
   14: Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( background_vid.js )
   15  # Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( look_up )
   16  

~/Desktop/projectname/blog/log/development.log:
    <binary>

~/Desktop/projectname/blog/tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/v3.0/-qjvx7_GiChDURpYYTnp8pEaJawjBzP6fBQuXrISdGM.cache:
    <binary>

~/Desktop/projectname/blog/tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/v3.0/0dY5SeQHyY-ZRlY9Vn1Ft4lozpK1gpyxSA25YklX8dY.cache:
    <binary>
(these cached files then repeat)
```

Comment: I'm not a ruby guy, but this whole example has me scratching my head.  Where does the array images get pushed to the DOM ?  Where is the element with id="background" ?  I'm suspecting you are forgetting about the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, but I don't see enough code to even make that statement.  No where do I see `<canvas id="background" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>`

Comment: Are you copying all of the code from `http://ekragency.com/demos/canvas-scroll/` ??